# Can Ionic or Cordova Support Managed App Configuration?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to grab and store the username string value from my MDM (AirWatch). I have been told this can be achieved by using [Managed App Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013823-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and was wondering if Ionic or Cordova can support this? I am building a hybrid app.

If not, is there anyone who has worked with the Managed App Config and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**For anyone looking to implement this functionality**

After researching the different plugins, this is the best one out there ( https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences ). Although the documentation is somewhat lacking (or was at least difficult for me to get started) so here are the things I did that were not mentioned:

After installing the plugin, run:

```
$ cordova prepare
```

This will generate a Settings.bundle file for you to put your key values in to.

Then go to platforms/ios/Settings.bundle and copy this into your xcode project Resources directory.

For whatever reason I still had some difficulty reading the keys so here is the structure I used for my **Root.plist** file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>Mango Farmer</string>  //username value
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>username</string>  //identifier value
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And in my **app.js** file here is the structure of the controller:

```
app.controller('GetUsername', function($scope) {

  $scope.testPref = function () {

  var prefs = window.plugins.appPreferences;
  prefs.fetch(prefReadSucess, prefReadFailed, 'username');

  function prefReadSucess(value) {
      console.log(value);
  }

  function prefReadFailed(error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
};
});
```

Hope that helps anyone interested!

Comment: Where are you meant to set the key-value pairs in a Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

### **SOLUTION**

This comes a bit too late but it might help other to solve the problem. A couple of years ago, several MDM/EMM providers (AirWatch included) created AppConfig, a standard set of APIs for managing devices an applications data.

Also, Oracle developed a Cordova plugin named "Cordova Plugin for EMM App Config". This plugin lets applications get configuration data (set from AirWatch's console) by using a single function.

```
cordova.plugins.EmmAppConfig.getValue("username");
```

This function is not available until after the deviceready event has fired, so you need to listen to that event before trying to use it. Below is a quick example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
     console.log(cordova.plugins.EmmAppConfig.getValue("username"));
}
```

You can find more information on this [article](https://imelgrat.me/phonegap/appconfig-cordova-emm/):